# Grep script to run on CD

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Im trying to learn some bash script writing and cleaning out some old CDs (remember those?)

What I have is a bunch of backup CDs with no rhyme or reason to them so I'd like to create a grep script that will search them based on keywords. (I'm currently trying to test the script first against the desktop) I know how to run grep, but its the scripting I'm having trouble with.

So here's what I have:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #CDGrepScript

 SOURCEDIR=/home/name/Desktop (I'm currently testing it with files on the desktop)
 #mount /dev/cdrom     
 #SOURCEDIR=/dev/cdrom

 echo "hello, $USER. I will search your files"
 echo Begin Search...

 grep -ir "taxes|personal|School" * 

 echo $results
 echo "The search is complete. Goodbye"

 exit
```

Now when I run this against files on the desktop.  My script hangs after "Begin search" What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be served better by a more general tool.  Like a rgrep (recursive grep) that will walk through a tree searching for a search term.  An example:

```
# rgrep
#
# Search for text strings in a directory hierarchy
set +x
case $# in
0 | 1 )
       # Not enough arguments -- give help message
       echo "Usage: $0 search_text pathname..." >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
* )
       # Use the first argument as a search string
       search_text=$1
       shift
       # Use the remaining argument(s) as path name(s)
       find "$@" -type f -print |
       while read pathname
       do
        egrep -i "$search_text" $pathname /dev/null
       done
       ;;
esac
```

Put this in your path, then you just change directories to the mount point for the CD-ROM, and type

```
$ rgrep "taxes" .
```

Or whatever other search you wish to perform.

Comment: Is rgrep not the same as grep -r much like egrep is similar is grep -E?  I've run grep before for basic searches.

Comment: Perhaps so.  I'm an old-timer, as such I have had that script laying around in a ~/bin folder since before grep had -r.  ;-)  I can't guess why your original scripts hangs on your desktop files, without knowing what the contents there are.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help.  It will take me some time to dissect the code since this is all new to me.  Until then....I'll get off your lawn! :) lol.

Comment: Btw, I just tested a slightly modified version of your script here.  I don't know why yours is hanging, but it didn't act as expected here.  Changing your grep -ir to egrep -ir made it work here.  You might try that simple change and see if it works for you.

Comment: Awesome! That I can do. Thanks!

Comment: Ok just ran it and its hanging at "Begin Script..." I only have one file on the desktop, so I'm not sure. Thanks though!

Comment: change directory to some place with only a few small files in it and run it from there.  It works fine here even on large text files, or dozens of similar files.  I suspect you have something (perhaps hidden) on your desktop that is hanging it up.

Comment: Ah, yes.  So the file I was running it against was a .pdf.  Can grep not work with PDFs?

Comment: PDF files typically do not work with grep, no.  There is a package on sourceforge (http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net) that may work for you.  I haven't tried it.

Comment: Well....darn it. I did just see that. Ill check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Hope it works out.  Let us know.